# Commit Storyboard to SVN Through Source Control in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, svn, storyboard

I'm new in using SVN. I committed my files in Xcode to svn successfully from Mac book, then I checked out the project in iMac, all he files are there but storyboard and few other files are empty and written in red.

Also, I can't commit the `storyboard` only `(ctrl+click -> source control -> commit selected files "Disabled")`.

Comment: right click your project in xcode -> Add files -> add StoryboardFiles to project -> clean -> build again

Comment: Proper way is to commit local changes, pull form server, remove conflicts , push your changes to server

Comment: @Muhammad Tanks a lot! I have commit, push, update, and refresh status. Is update the same as pull?

Comment: you should commit ->update-(remove confilcts) ->push to server

Answer (score 1):

```
(ctrl+click -> source control -> commit selected files "Disabled")
```

This is Xcode's source control(not svn).
   You should do like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry this is Chinese version.You should right click your project->choose serve->choose commit to SVN.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but i couldn't find choose server :(